# Arduino bootloading

Tags: programmer, bootloader

First of all I am new to Arduino so sorry if I am being a bit stupid. I want to use an atemga 328 32kb tqfp micro controller integrated on a PCB. I understand that the chip does not come with a boot loader. What can I do to burn the boot loader on this chip? is it possible to buy this micro controller with a pre programmed boot loader? If the chip has a bootloader, can I use the arduino Uno as a programmer and reprogram the chip multiple times while it is in the pcb?

Comment: So are you trying to integrate a stand alone uC, or put a new uC on your Arduino board?

Comment: Yes, you can buy them preprogrammed with an Arduino bootloader, if you don't have something available to program your first.

Answer (score 5):

It is pretty easy to burn a bootloader using either a programmers like [AVR-ISP](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/products/tools_card.asp?tool_id=2726), [USBtinyISP](http://www.ladyada.net/make/usbtinyisp/) or another arduino.
I followed this tutorial and was able to make it happen: [ArduinoToBreadboard](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoToBreadboard)
[image]

I used the SPI/ISP burn the bootloader and then an FTDI cable to push code changes. It was really simple.

Comment: This setup works wonders, I use it for ATtiny's too.

Comment: I bought a boot loaded MC chip, integrated it in stand alone mode on the board board, and was able to reprogram it using RX,TX,Reset,VCC and GND.

Now I am thinking of using a jumper on the PCB with tracks leading to Tx,rx,Vcc,GND and reset of the atmega 328p, and reprogram it using the UNO. I think I can use an FT232RL USB to Serial and do the same connections. In this way I can reprogram without the arduino while still using arduino software right?

thanks very much for your help guys

Comment: @WarrenGauci Yep, you should be able to load arduino sketches using those pins via an UNO or FTDI. To burn a new bootloader you would need to use the SPI setup shown above.